# With a powered eSATA, what's the difference between GND_DRAIN and the USB's GND?

Tags: usb, esata

Can I just connect GND_DRAIN to the GND?

[eSATAp pinout](http://www.addonics.com/emerging_technologies/images/usb3_usb3B_pinout_lrg.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[eSATAp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESATAp) ports are a mixed connector that does both powered eSATA *and* USB.

The GND_DRAIN is actually part of the USB3 standard, not eSATA.

The GND-DRAIN pin is used as a signal/data ground (return), and the GND is used as a power ground.

[More info on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Connectors)

Comment: So does that mean GND_DAIN is not conected to the USB's GND?
Let's say I have a eSATAp port on my pc and a SATA Harddisk, then I want to connect the HDD to the eSATAp port. Can I just connect together the 3 GNDs from the SATA HDD data pins then connect it to the eSATAp's GND_DRAIN? Then connect the TX, RX pins and provide power to the HDD... Will it work?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Data_connector
http://www.ayagroup.com/images/USB3.0_SuperSpeed_Tutorial.jpg